# How to configure OpenVpn server with multiple clients using asymethric key

Tags: linux, openvpn, encryption

### Introduction

I want to configure OpenVpn with 2 clients and 1 server but i only mannage to use it with 1 server and 1 client.

### Setup

```
Server ip: 10.10.102.146
Client ips: 10.10.102.138
```

Server configuration (tunel.conf):

```
local 10.10.102.143
remote 10.10.102.38
dev tun1
port 5555
comp-lzo
user nobody
ping 15
ifconfig 172.160.0.1 172.160.0.2
secret /etc/openvpn/clave.key
```

Client configuration (tunel.conf)

```
local 10.10.102.138
remote 10.10.102.143
dev tun1
port 5555
comp-lzo
ping 15
ifconfig 172.160.0.2 172.160.0.1
secret /etc/openvpn/clave.key
```

> clave.key is the asymetrhic key

Then I use the following command, first on the server and then on the client:
`openvpn --verb 5 --config /etc/openvpn/tunel.conf`

### Problems

I want to both clients connect at the same time and having the ips `172.160.0.2` and `172.160.0.3`

### What I've tried

I tried to add a third ip on ifconfig and an extra remote but It doesn't follows the right syntax so it gives an error when running.

Comment: You going wrong way. Don't use `--ifconfig` directive in the server config. Read man openvpn ( https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage ), about `--server` or `--server-bridge` directives. Any answer will more or less be cite from that manual page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I needed to use the server mode since by default it uses peer to peer which wasn't suitable for the environment I was looking for.

### Client config:

```
port 5555
proto udp
dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert servidor-vpn-lsi.crt
key servidor-vpn-lsi.key
dh dh.pem
tls-crypt ta.key

#COMPROBAMOS LOS CERTIFICADOS DE LOS CLIENTES (MAYOR SEGURIDAD)

remote-cert-tls client

#MODIFICAMOS EL CIFRADO SIMETRICO DEL CANAL DE DATOS, EL CANAL DE CONTROL TLS Y EL ALGORITMO PARA VERIFICAR LA INTEGRIDAD.
#SI USAMOS AES-256-GCM NO ES NECESARIO PONER LA DIRECTIVA AUTH YA QUE NO SE UTILIZA.

cipher AES-256-GCM
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
auth SHA512

#TOPOLOGIA DE LA RED (SE RECOMIENDA SUBNET) Y SUBRED VIRTUAL DONDE ESTARAN LOS CLIENTES.

topology subnet
server 172.160.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
compress lz4-v2
max-clients 100

user nobody
group nogroup



persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

### Server config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp

#ESTA DIRECTIVA ES LA DE CONEXION CON LA IP PUBLICA O DOMINIO DEL SERVIDOR OPENVPN, TAMBIEN TENEMOS QUE PONER EL MISMO PUERTO DEL SERVIDOR

#remote 127.0.0.1 5555
remote 10.10.102.143 5555


resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

ca ca.crt
cert cliente2-vpn-lsi.crt
key cliente2-vpn-lsi.key
tls-crypt ta.key

remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-GCM
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
auth SHA512


compress lz4-v2
verb 3

ifconfig 172.160.0.3 172.160.0.1
```